# Copy Value from table to table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have two tables first table like this
Table 1 name id groups contain 2 field

1. id_gr
2. name

Table 2 name Product Contain a lot of field and contain one field name id_gr contain the id_gr Id's from table one i need to replace the Id with the id value

```
id_dr  | name
-----------------
1      | group1
2      | group2
2      | group2
```

The product table is like this

```
product_id | name     | group
-----------------------------
1          | proudct1 |     1
2          | proudct1 |     2
3          | proudct1 |     3
```

I need to replace the id in group in product table with its value from group table instead of id.

Comment: Can you improve your formatting? maybe some punctuation signs? it's impossible to understand anything

Comment: is this ok now i tried to format it but i could not

Comment: Your design is lacking... You should read up about relational database design, specifically, [normalization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Relational_Database_Design/Normalization)

Comment: Why you want to replace group id with the string values, you can easily join the tables to show the group name in case you want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table2, table1 SET table2.group = table1.name where table2.group = table1.id
```

Just for clarification:

table2 is the one with 3 columns

table1 is the one with to columns